# Error Excepción null en DataReader

Tags: mysql, c#, mvc

Hola a todos estoy terminando un proyecto y uso el MVC en el mismo, trato de devolver un DataReader pero no comprendo como inicializarlo para que no me de error

**Código Modelo**

```
        public MySqlDataReader mBloqueados()
    {
        MySqlDataReader registro = null;
        string sql = "SELECT idUsuario,bloqueado FROM usuario WHERE bloqueado = '0';";

        MySqlConnection conexion = Conexion.getConexion();

        conexion.Open();

        try
        {
            MySqlCommand comando = new MySqlCommand(sql, conexion);
            comando.ExecuteNonQuery();

            registro = comando.ExecuteReader();
        }
        catch(MySqlException ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Error :" + ex.Message);
        }
        finally
        {
            conexion.Close();
        }

        return registro;
    }
```

En este como verán tengo el DataReader en null ya que si no lo tengo iniciado en un valor este mismo me dara error al retornar pero el problema ahora es con la vista

**Código Vista**

```
private void cargarDesbloqueados()
    {
        dGVBloquear.Rows.Clear();
        Modelo.Modelo modelo = new Modelo.Modelo();
        MySqlDataReader registro = modelo.mDesbloqueados();

        if (registro.HasRows)
        {
            while (registro.Read())
            {
                int n = dGVBloquear.Rows.Add();

                dGVBloquear.Rows[n].Cells[0].Value = registro["idUsuario"].ToString();
                dGVBloquear.Rows[n].Cells[1].Value = registro["bloqueado"].ToString();

            }
        }
        
    }
```

El problema es que como no tengo ningún usuario bloqueado entonces el DataReader no me va a encontrar una coincidencia y me queda null pero entonces me da error

[image: El error que me sale]

Creo que en si es porque debería iniciarla con otro valor pero no se como inicializarla para que no me de error gracias a los que me digan que estoy haciendo mal

Comment: Hola, lo que puedes hacer es agregar en el if si es null tu modelo, por que ahi el error es por que como tu comentas viene nulo, puedes usar el if(registro != null && registro.HasRows), no recuerdo ahorita si con un & te analiza los dos o usando dos &&, pero prueba las 2 formas if(registro != null & registro.HasRows), if(registro != null && registro.HasRows), a ver si con eso funciona

Answer (score 0):

No necesitas inicializar la variable registro, con controlar que su valor no sea nulo evitaras el error

```
if (registro != null && registro.HasRows)
        {
            while (registro.Read())
            {
                int n = dGVBloquear.Rows.Add();

                dGVBloquear.Rows[n].Cells[0].Value = registro["idUsuario"].ToString();
                dGVBloquear.Rows[n].Cells[1].Value = registro["bloqueado"].ToString();

            }
        }
```

Utiliza el operador && para evaluar primero si *registro != null*, de modo que si esto no se cumple la segunda parte de la expresion **ya no se evalua** *registro.HasRows*, ya que al evaluar esta expresion daria un error de *NullReference* porque un *null* no puede tener una propiedad *HasRows*

Mas info sobre los operadores:
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/boolean-logical-operators